# render static content of html page using text file

Tags: html

I have a scenario where I need to create simple html page having large amount of text.So i want to make use of some text file,which I can have in my content folder of mvc vb.net solution.so next time,if i want to change my content ,I can change in that text file only.I can only use java script and html to achieve this.
I tried using java script to load file and that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it via JavaScript but in a very crude way. Yuo would need to write a script that requests the text file via AJAX and then puts the resulting content into a specific tag on the current page.